# Wikipedia NewPP limit report Parsed by mw1079

Tags: mediawiki, performance-testing

I opened [a page wikipedia about 'em' in typography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)). By curiosity, I used the google dev tool (inspect element) to have look at the page's html source code. I find the following code which is very strange to me but I guess this is something very useful for performance analysis. How is it generated and by whom?

[image]

Comment: It's generated here: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/MW/browse/master/includes/parser/Parser.php

Comment: also, retagging this as `mediawiki`, as this is not specific for Wikipedia in any way

Comment: Thank you! So is there some documentation about theses codes?

Comment: [Wikipedia:Template limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Template_limits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML comment is a feature designed to help users fix pages and templates which hit the parser limits. It's controlled by [$wgEnableParserLimitReporting](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEnableParserLimitReporting).

Comment: [Here is a GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/ernstki/1c897946cfa6dd84065e1e313a9f6376) that shows you how to disable the "Saved in parser cache with key" message as well, if you were wanting to suppress both of those in the output (as I was). Unfortunately, it involves patching the MediaWiki source (for each new release, and that gist's patch file will probably stop working someday), because there is no corresponding `LocalSettings.php` setting to control this within [`includes/parser/ParserCache.php`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/ParserCache_8php_source.html#l00297)